# Select top score only from MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL statement that pulls back the top 15 scores from a table of users.

```
select @rownum:=@rownum+1 'rank', driverName, teamColour, totalScore, totalTime, didTyreChange from entries p, (SELECT @rownum:=0) r WHERE totalTime > 1000 and progress = 19 order by totalScore desc, totalTime asc limit 15
```

The conditions are, that the player must have completed all the questions (where progress = 19) and the final time must be more than 1 second (totalTime > 1000). The statement also returns their rank as a variable (@rownum:=@rownum+1 'rank').

The result of this query is the following

[image: MySQL Results]

What I now want to do, is extend the results to only show a players top score. I have had a look at `DISTINCT`  and `GROUP BY` but get these results with the following `GROUP BY` statement

```
select @rownum:=@rownum+1 'rank', driverName, teamColour, totalScore, totalTime, didTyreChange from entries p, (SELECT @rownum:=0) r WHERE totalTime > 1000 and progress = 19 group by driverName order by totalScore desc, totalTime asc limit 15
```

[image: Group by results]

and nowhere with `DISTINCT` as I get error code 1064. I have tried both

```
select @rownum:=@rownum+1 'rank', DISTINCT(driverName), teamColour, totalScore, totalTime, didTyreChange from entries p, (SELECT @rownum:=0) r WHERE totalTime > 1000 and progress = 19 order by totalScore desc, totalTime asc limit 15
```

and

```
select DISTINCT driverName, @rownum:=@rownum+1 'rank', teamColour, totalScore, totalTime, didTyreChange from entries p, (SELECT @rownum:=0) r WHERE totalTime > 1000 and progress = 19 order by totalScore desc, totalTime asc limit 15
```

Neither provides the desired results. I'm wondering if there is an easy way to achieve this within the statement, or to do it on the PHP side of things instead.

The desired resultL

```
viper         1  9810
Maverick      2 25420
Racer roasty  3 28850
.. .
...          15
```

In other words, no user should appear in the results twice, only the quickest totalTime is displayed for each user.

Slimmed down SQLFiddle here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/36d3dc/7 (8000 char limit reached).

Comment: can you correctly explain the desired result?

Comment: Sure, question updated

Comment: Brother your explanation is still confusing. please explain more and in detail

Comment: can you post the group by query?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15410336/how-to-select-top-n-rows-from-each-group-id-in-same-table?lq=1

Comment: Added group by query and a bit more detail on the desired result

Comment: @Strawberry sqlfiddle in question

Comment: There is no viper in the data set. In consequence, this result set will be hard to achieve.

Comment: @Strawberry SQL Fiddle updated with correct recordset

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT @i:=@i+1 rank, a.*
  FROM 
     ( SELECT x.*
         FROM entries x
         JOIN (SELECT drivername, MIN(totaltime) min_totaltime FROM entries WHERE progress = 19 AND totaltime > 1000 GROUP BY drivername) y
           ON y.drivername = x.drivername
          AND y.min_totaltime = x.totaltime
     ) a
     , (SELECT @i:=0) i
 ORDER 
    BY totalScore desc, totalTime asc;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/36d3dc/17

Comment: That is applying the rank to the recordset before ordering, therefore the rank is actually incorrect. When this is applied to the full data set, viper comes out at rank #139.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem correctly then below query will help you:

```
select *,@rownum:=@rownum+1 as 'rank' from (select * from (select  driverName, teamColour, totalScore, totalTime, didTyreChange from entries p WHERE totalTime > 1000 and progress = 19 order by totalScore desc, totalTime asc  )a group by driverName)c , (select @rownum:=0)f
```

Comment: @PeteSimmons. If you're going to use the evil star (and you shouldn't), it has to go first.

Comment: @Strawberry yeah, want to avoid that like the plague! As I have in my original statement

Comment: @pete I have update my query now try.. It will be great if you can load your data in sqlfiddle then I can test my query before posting here

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
select @rownum:=@rownum+1 'rank', driverName, totalScore, MIN(totalTime) 
from entries p, (SELECT @rownum:=0) r 
WHERE totalTime > 1000 and progress = 19 
group by driverName 
order by totalScore desc, totalTime asc
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/36d3dc/20/0